# Help with finding a limit - multivariable

Tags: calculus, limits

can someone help me to find this limit ?
I tried setting $y= \lambda x$ but for $\lambda = \pm 1 $ we have problem

$ \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{yx^2}{x^2-y^2}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What paths to choose to prove that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2 - y^2}$ does not exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219144/what-paths-to-choose-to-prove-that-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracxy2x2-y2) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7B(x%2Cy)%5Cto(0%2C0)%7D%5Cfrac%7Byx%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2-y%5E2%7D%24&p=1) through a duplicate [How to calculate $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2 - y^2}$](/q/3847944). Note there are other duplicates, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [No limit for $\frac{x^2 y}{x^2-y^2}$ when $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1483887/602049), [To evaluate multivariable limit $\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^2-y^2}$](/q/1615375), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: @Hello Please make sure to search the site for your question next time ;)

Comment: I don’t agree with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1219156/715008), however I agree with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847949/715008). Reason I don’t agree with first is that you can’t choose y=0 in a “$\to 0$” expression where y never reaches zero.

Comment: @WindSoul - in any limit, only the value of the function at the limit point itself is excluded from consideration. Here, that limit point is $(0,0)$. thus the approach to that point where $y = 0$, but $x \ne 0$, is just as relevant as any other curve approaching $(0,0)$.